# postgres local schema qualifier

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am using postgres schemas to group views and functions and to keep multiple versions of them in a database (sometimes needed for backwards compatibility) since there are multiple versions of the same function in different schemas i cannot simply reference it by name but need to write the full qualified name "schema.funcname" to  access it.

when referencing functions within schemaA from another function in schemaA i always have to write schemaA.funcname. this bugs me when i rename the schema later - is there a qualifier indicating that the function in the same schema schould be used? maybe like the "this" qualifier in java?

hope it can be understood what i am meaning

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) to change search path for current session:

```
create schema test1;
create schema test2;

create function test1.f() returns int as $body$ begin return 1; end; $body$ language plpgsql;
create function test2.f() returns int as $body$ begin return 2; end; $body$ language plpgsql;

set schema 'test1';
select f();

set schema 'test2';
select f();
```

You can also add [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) to function definition:

```
create or replace function test1.x() returns int as $body$ begin return 1; end; $body$ language plpgsql;
create or replace function test1.f() returns int as $body$ begin return x(); end; $body$ language plpgsql set search_path = 'test1';

create or replace function test2.x() returns int as $body$ begin return 2; end; $body$ language plpgsql;
create or replace function test2.f() returns int as $body$ begin return x(); end; $body$ language plpgsql set search_path = 'test2';

select test1.f();

select test2.f();
```

Comment: thx for the answer - i know set schema but it is not what i want to do since it affects the whole session. calling f from a function in test1 would then call the same function as calling f from a function in test2. I want functions test1 to call test1.f() and functions in test2 to call test2.f()

Comment: You can also add `search_path` to function definition, see my updated answer. Is this what you  need? If no, that I am out of ideas.

Comment: in a way - it s not exactly what i was looking for but it may be useful- i will think about it. thanks for the tip anyway